# How do you put multiple data items with own unique key on another unique key?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

Im making an ordering system where there is a product,supplier and order table. What I'm trying to do is when you order, it can have multiple product and one supplier. Example us OrderID 001 it can have 3 products from product table and 1 supplier from supplier table. How can I do this?
Sorry for asking too much but I don't have a code yet for this part of the system as I don't know where to begin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Orders Table.
Add all ordered products to the order Table.

In the table the three products would all have the same order_id, but a different or (in case someone bought two of the same) same product. You will also need to track the amount they purchase with each row, in case the amount changes.

```
Select Sum(purchase_amount) from orders where order_id = "YOUR_ORDER_ID"
Select * from orders where order_id = "YOUR_ORDER_ID"
...3 rows show up
```

You may want to have an order_summary table as well that contains the total amount, etc.

Comment: Ohh thank you I somehow gets it now. So I will have separate table for product order and order?

Comment: Yes, That would be the best approach.